# Initiate message action on MS Teams and read the content of the message

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a working **composeExtension** (message extension) in Microsoft Teams.

One of the commands is `query`, and on selecting an item on the list will post a hero card in the chat.

The next thing, I am looking for is triggering `action` command on the message and generate an adaptive card with preloaded information from the message itself.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and going over MS Documentation - [Define messaging extension action commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/define-action-command)

*Below solution is in NodeJS*

**Step 1: Update Manifest File**

```
...

"composeExtensions": [
   ...
   "commands": [
       ...
       {
          "id": "Action",
          "type": "action",
          "title": "Action",
          "description": "Test command to run action on message context (message sharing)",
          "context": [ "message" ]
       }
       ...
   ]
   ...
]
...
```

**Step 2: Handling the request**

```
async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask(context, action) {

   ...
   if( action.commandId === 'Action') {

       // here you can return anything eg: adaptive card
     
       // below helper function will read the content of the message

       let cardContent = await this.getAdaptiveCardContent(context);
       let CardData = JSON.parse(cardContent);

   }
   ...

}

async getAdaptiveCardContent(context) {
   if (!context.hasOwnProperty("_activity") || !context._activity.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
            return null;
   }

   let messagePayload = context._activity.value.messagePayload;

   if (messagePayload) {
       for (let i = 0, attachment; i < messagePayload.attachments.length; i++) {
         attachment = messagePayload.attachments[i];
         if (attachment.contentType === "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero") { // In my case its a adaptive card
                    return attachment.content;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, yes it is solved using the above solution.